# Sensor Orientation (XYZF) to Lat/Long? triangulation required?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, sensormodel

I have IAGA2002 data regarding Magnetic North, as read from Sensor Orientation (XYZF), documented here: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/IAGA/vdat/IAGA2002/iaga2002format.html

Example data is:

```
 Format                 IAGA-2002                                    |
 Source of Data         IPGP                                         |
 Station Name           ADDIS ABABA                                  |
 IAGA CODE              AAE                                          |
 Geodetic Latitude      09.033                                       |
 Geodetic Longitude     038.767                                      |
 Elevation              2442                                         |
 Reported               XYZF                                         |
 Sensor Orientation     HDZF                                         |
 Digital Sampling       1 hour                                       |
 Data Interval Type     1-hour (00:30 - 01:29)                       |
 Data Type              definitive                                   |
DATE       TIME         DOY     AAEX      AAEY      AAEZ      AAEF   |
2004-01-01 00:00:00.000 001     36034.50    859.60   1318.10  36068.40
2004-01-01 01:00:00.000 001     36037.10    861.60   1318.80  36071.00
2004-01-01 02:00:00.000 001     36042.20    861.70   1319.10  36076.10
2004-01-01 03:00:00.000 001     36035.20    864.40   1321.10  36069.20
2004-01-01 04:00:00.000 001     36018.20    859.30   1322.60  36052.20
2004-01-01 05:00:00.000 001     36017.70    867.10   1330.10  36052.10
2004-01-01 06:00:00.000 001     36041.60    880.30   1332.20  36076.40
```

Given the (station-name)X, Y, Z, F parameters, and perhaps the source location (Geodetic Lat/Long listed in the headers), how might I derive a specific Lat/Long.

And, will I need to triangulate with multiple stations (which I have many of)?

Answer (score 1):

AAEXs, AAEYs and AAEZs are not any absolute or relative coordinates, but the (observed/recorded) directions of the magnetic field in the X, Y and Z directions (expressed) in nano Tesla (nT).

The measurement device (i.e., "sensor") was placed at 09.033 North 038.767 East and 2442 meter above the Mean Sea Level (most probably EGM2008).